# How to encapsulate a TCP packet with a UDP header using Scapy?

Tags: networking, tcp, udp, scapy

I have been trying to encapsulate a TCP packet inside a custom UDP header using scapy. To create the packet, I use the command:

```
a = IP(dst = "142.251.33.110") / UDP() / IP(dst = "104.215.148.63") / TCP()
```

From what I understand, this should create a TCP packet with an outer UDP header (the IPs are of random websites). However, when I use Wireshark to inspect the packets, it shows the protocol as DNS and the protocol is malformed as well (probably because it is expecting a DNS packet and getting a different one).

How do I resolve this issue?

Comment: Absent using a tunnel protocol that uses UDP as its transport protocol, encapsulating a TCP _segment_ (not packet) inside a UDP _datagram_ (not packet) makes no sense because TCP uses connections between the TCPs, and UDP is connectionless. TCP uses a handshake to create and tear down connections, and UDP cannot pass its payload to TCP.

Comment: Ah I see. What I wanted to achieve was to create a "fake" UDP header and encapsulate an encrypted TCP segment inside it. So basically, to the outside observer it looks like a normal UDP datagram. However, when this reaches me, I can decapsulate the outer UDP header to decrypt and extract the TCP segment. Is this possible?

Comment: You are describing an encrypted VPN that uses UDP as the transport protocol. There are such VPNs. You could also use common encrypted VPNs that use TCP (encapsulating TCP inside TCP). Just about any VPN will encrypt its payload.